# Can't reference frequent item sets to column name

Tags: python, pandas, apriori

I am applying the Apriori algorithm to a bank dataset to find the rules. I converted the output to a list that looks like this:

```
RelationRecord(
    items=frozenset({'NO', 'FEMALE', 'YES'}), 
    support=0.4083333333333333, 
    ordered_statistics=[
        OrderedStatistic(
            items_base=frozenset({'FEMALE'}), 
            items_add=frozenset({'NO', 'YES'}), 
            confidence=0.8166666666666667, 
            lift=1.0061601642710472)
        ,
        OrderedStatistic(
            items_base=frozenset({'NO'}), 
            items_add=frozenset({'FEMALE', 'YES'}), 
            confidence=0.4969574036511156, 
            lift=1.0039543508103346)
        ,
        OrderedStatistic(
            items_base=frozenset({'FEMALE', 'YES'}), 
            items_add=frozenset({'NO'}), 
            confidence=0.8249158249158249, 
            lift=1.0039543508103346)
        ,
        OrderedStatistic(
            items_base=frozenset({'NO', 'YES'}), 
            items_add=frozenset({'FEMALE'}), 
            confidence=0.5030800821355236, 
            lift=1.0061601642710472
        )
    ]
)
```

The original dataframe has columns like 'married', 'mortgage' with values yes or no. The problem is that in the frozen set, I cannot know which columns those values correspond to. For example, 'Female' is to gender column. But other 'yes', 'no' cannot be referenced back to the original column. How do I get the columns for which the items are in the frozen set?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should provide a concrete minimal example

Comment: you are using Apriori from which library?

Comment: If you transform your original data via e.g. a OneHotEncoder, you can create column names like `married_yes`, `married_no` etc. This will clarify the meaning of the values. Please show us your current code so we can understand the procedure.